# How to get a GeometryReader to work only in one dimension?

Tags: swiftui

I am using a Geometry Reader to control the horizontal layout of some child views in a HStack. The child views must finally be equally spaced and their numbers are not fixed. This works fine without any problems.

However, the vertical layout, which is solely determined by the content (child views), is expanded to max available height by the geometry reader (which is standard behaviour).

Any suggestions on how to overcome this behaviour are welcome?

(Another way of explaining the problem is to say that a **Horizontal Geometry Reader** would solve the problem)

Hereby a code snippet added for clarity:

```
public struct ToolbarView: View {
    
    @ObservedObject public var viewModel: ToolbarViewModel
    
    public var body: some View
    {
        GeometryReader { geometry in
            
            HStack(spacing:0) {
                ForEach(self.viewModel.items.filter({ $0.visible })) { item in
                    ToolbarItemView(itemViewModel:item, toolbarViewModel: self.viewModel)
                        .frame(width:geometry.size.width / CGFloat(Double(self.viewModel.items.count)))
                        .font(self.viewModel.textFont)
                }
            }
        }.frame(height:CGFloat(50))
    }
}
```

Comment: Equally spaced views in an HStack shouldn't need a GR. What's the GR doing here?

Comment: Would you just show instead your code and point to the problem?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake explaining the problem. A view consists of an image with text below. Both are centered vertically. To look good all the views must be equal size. A GeometryReader is used to get equal size. I have considered to use Spacers to obtain the same, but this will not work with appearance requirements due to varying length of text. Again, this all works fine, but the GeometryReader make troubles with layout in the vertical axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you note in the comments, Spacers will fix this without a GR. You just need to put them in an HStack:

```
HStack(spacing:0) {
    ForEach(self.viewModel.items.filter({ $0.visible })) { item in
        HStack {
            Spacer()
            ToolbarItemView(itemViewModel:item, toolbarViewModel: self.viewModel)
                .font(self.viewModel.textFont)
            Spacer()
        }
    }.frame(height:CGFloat(50))
}
```